# Why there's not mapKeys in Data.Hashmap?

Tags: haskell

I want to use function such as `mapKeys` to `map` over only keys. There is namely function `mapKeys` in `Data.Map`, but no analogues in `Data.Hashmap`. Moreover, in `Data.Hashmap` I have found nothing about manipulating keys. Is there only incompleteness of `Data.Hashmap` module or exists any ideological reasons don't do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hashmap achieves good performance by determining the location of the value by applying a hash function on the key. Mapping over the keys would involve pulling each element out of the map and reinserting it using a hash of the new key. This is all doable, of course, but is quite a lot of work, and so it possibly best avoided.

Comment: Good answer. But what if I just want a map-like API, not necessarily implemented with hashed keys?