# Why no mapKeys in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

The Scala Collection library has `mapValues` and `filterKeys`. The reason it doesn't have `mapKeys` is likely the performance aspect (with regard to `HashMap` implementation), as discussed here for Haskell: [Why there's not mapKeys in Data.Hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227047/why-theres-not-mapkeys-in-data-hashmap)

However.

Performance implications aside, I find myself needing `mapKeys` at least as much as `mapValues`, simply for massaging data (i.e. I'm using a map for data abstraction, not for its fetch speed).

Am I wrong, and which data model would you use for this? Tuples?

Comment: If mapping the keys produces a collision, which of the values do you expect to find in the new map? The first, the last, or the collection of all values with the same key?

Comment: Good point. In my case I would guarantee no collisions, but that goes to show how much needs to be considered in designing collection libraries.

Comment: @LeifWickland, the same as happens when you map on a `Set` in Scala: it may get smaller.

Answer (score 12):

No idea why it's not in standard library, but you can easily pimp your library with implicit class

```
  implicit class MapFunctions[A, B](val map: Map[A, B]) extends AnyVal {
    def mapKeys[A1](f: A => A1): Map[A1, B] = map.map({ case (a, b) => (f(a), b) })
  }

  val m = Map(1 -> "aaa", 2 -> "bbb")

  println(m.mapKeys(_ + 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use scalaz:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._

val m = Map(1 -> "aaa", 2 -> "bbb")
m.mapKeys(_ + 1)
```

In case of collisions the result may be smaller than the original Map.

Comment: Scalaz is like Boost for C++, and I am not touching it for the same reasons.

Comment: Agree. And I think it should serve also as a pool of ideas for scala compiler devs. I have no idea why they don't consider them. This method mapKeys is a clear example every developer would expect in the collection library.

Comment: Boost becomes your platform instead of C++. Same easily for Scalaz. It changes the abstraction level so considerably that there's no turning back. This also means higher threshold for getting involved with the code base. I'm not the only one seeing boost in this light. --- As to the original question, I am nowadays quite happy with no mapKeys. Using partial functions to catch both key and value. It's actually rarely I would want to map only the key part.

Comment: Scalaz (and Cats) are libraries that introduce support for proper statically typed functional programming. Of course, you don't need them if you prefer OO style of programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be related to collision resolution.
Different keys after map may get the same values, e.g. "Key"=>key, "KEY"=>key
It is unclear how to resolve this type of conflicts without changing the value type (Set?) or overriding values which might be undesirable.